# Update Same Contents on every Page

Tags: multisite, pages

I have same Table on 10 different pages. 
Table is basically of prices and rates.
I have to update it every once a day or week.
The problem is I have to update it opening every page.
yes I do copy paste after editing one table.
But i want to know if there is a method to update the table, which will the then reflect the update to all the table.
All the tables are exact and same.

Answer (score 0):

Show the values of the table form database on the frontend and update the value in the database if any value changed in any table then there is no need to change the table on each page. You can create the short-code for the table and used it on any page where you want.